# OpenVPN all trafic through but no access to remote LAN

Tags: openvpn, nat, internal-dns

Goal: be able to route all the trafic through the OpenVPN server and being able to communicate with the remote DNS (127.128.129.130) and the remote LAN (12x.x.x.x)

I have added to the OpenVPN client config file `redirect-gateway def1`.

As decribed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/578550/865256), I have added the three rules to iptables (in case the post is deleted):

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 \
     -s 10.8.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED \
     -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 \
      -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Which works great except that I cannot resolve hosts on my private DNS. I might be due to the first FORWARD rule which forward all trafic from `tun0` to `eth0`.

How can I do so the trafic to the remote DNS and LAN does not go away?

Comment: If you're going to change IP addresses, then just replce the first byte with 10. 127/8 is the loopback network and won't get routed. The first rule doesn't *do* the forwarding, it *allows* the forwarding; subtle difference.

Comment: I missed your comment. Thanks for the clarification on routing. I don't understand the byte change. Could you explain?

Comment: You've hidden the real IP address of your DNS server and used 127.128.129.30. 127.*.*.* (otherwise known as 127/8) is NOT routed out of your system. So if you want to hide the real IP address, replace the first number a.k.a. byte with 10 (and not 127), so that it still makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not using the remote dns server. You can use openvpn to set the dns server too. Then the name resolution for your private network should work.

```
 push "dhcp-option DNS 127.128.129.130"
```

See here:
https://openvpn.net/community-resources/pushing-dhcp-options-to-clients/

Comment: I am already pushing dns, sorry, it's not explicit in my post.

Comment: @Kaymaz, does it also get set in client interface? You can check it with ipconfig. You may also try adding domain name too `push dhcp-option DOMAIN example.local`. Apart from that, what client are you using?

Comment: I'm pushing DNS through the client config. I'm using OpenVPN GUI for Windows.

Comment: @Kaymaz, first thing to check would be to see if it gets assigned correctly. Can you see it using ipconfig?

Comment: Yes I do. In fact the configuration client/server works well (DNS access, remote LAN, internet access). I lose DNS and remote LAN access only when I send all my internet traffic through OpenVPN